# Does _access search the PATH environment?

Tags: windows, file-io, path

I have a Windows application using `_access` to check a file's existence. It's on the `%PATH%`, but `_access` reports that the file doesn't exist. Am I to take it that it's not searching the `%PATH%`?

If so, what's the accepted method of checking for a file's existence on the `%PATH%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `PathFindOnPath`, which is [described on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773594%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Quoting from the **Remarks** section:

[image]